# as.POSIXct returns NAs without apparent reason

Tags: r, date, character, posixct

I'm struggling with the conversion of character strings to dates with `as.POSIXct` function, as it gives NA for some rows but not for others. Here's a piece of my data

```
            Fecha     hora  Lt.s
165397 30/03/2014  0:30:00  4.76
165398 30/03/2014  0:45:00  3.66
165399 30/03/2014  1:00:00  3.84
165400 30/03/2014  1:15:00  3.84
165401 30/03/2014  1:30:00  4.38
165402 30/03/2014  1:45:00  5.14
165403 30/03/2014  2:00:00  7.22
165404 30/03/2014  2:15:00 10.77
165405 30/03/2014  2:30:00 11.79
165406 30/03/2014  2:45:00 13.12
165407 30/03/2014  3:00:00 13.12
165408 30/03/2014  3:15:00 13.12
165409 30/03/2014  3:30:00 13.12
165410 30/03/2014  3:45:00 13.66
```

so I paste the two first columns, and then convert it to POSIX:

```
dat$datehour <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat$Fecha, dat$hora),format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and this is what I get:

```
            Fecha    hora  Lt.s            datehour
165397 30/03/2014 0:30:00  4.76 2014-03-30 00:30:00
165398 30/03/2014 0:45:00  3.66 2014-03-30 00:45:00
165399 30/03/2014 1:00:00  3.84 2014-03-30 01:00:00
165400 30/03/2014 1:15:00  3.84 2014-03-30 01:15:00
165401 30/03/2014 1:30:00  4.38 2014-03-30 01:30:00
165402 30/03/2014 1:45:00  5.14 2014-03-30 01:45:00
165403 30/03/2014 2:00:00  7.22                <NA>
165404 30/03/2014 2:15:00 10.77                <NA>
165405 30/03/2014 2:30:00 11.79                <NA>
165406 30/03/2014 2:45:00 13.12                <NA>
165407 30/03/2014 3:00:00 13.12 2014-03-30 03:00:00
165408 30/03/2014 3:15:00 13.12 2014-03-30 03:15:00
165409 30/03/2014 3:30:00 13.12 2014-03-30 03:30:00
165410 30/03/2014 3:45:00 13.66 2014-03-30 03:45:00
```

My data frame is way bigger, and it does the same for other random rows, but I am not capable of identifying the reason of this error, and the means to solve it. Can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like daylight saving time in your timezone (i.e. there's no 0200 hour).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Good catch! This explains why I got *different* NA values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to daylight savings time in your timezone.

```
as.POSIXct('30/03/2014 2:00:00', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', tz='CET')
# [1] NA

as.POSIXct('30/03/2014 2:00:00', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', tz='EST')
# [1] "2014-03-30 02:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about this. What's exactly daylight savings?

Comment: From wikipedia: [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)